# NSAutoReleasePool and async functions

Tags: c#, cocoa, monomac

I have a function in my program that creates new widgets to represent data, however whenever a widget is created i get alot of "AutoRelease with no NSAutoReleasePool in place" error messages. Since an NSAutoReleasePool should be automatically created on the main thread, I have an inkling that these error messages appear because an async function might create my threads...

This is the function called to create widgets to represent the latest information. This function is called pretty often:

```
    private void CreateAndDisplayTvShowWidget (TvShow show)
    {
        var Widget = new TvShowWidgetController (show);
        Widget.OnRemoveWidget += ConfirmRemoveTvShow;

        Widget.View.SetFrameOrigin (new PointF (0, -150));
        Widget.View.SetFrameSize (new SizeF (ContentView.Frame.Width, 150));

        ContentView.AddSubview (Widget.View);
        show.ShowWidget = Widget;
    }
```

This function is usually called when this async function returns:

```
    private static void WebRequestCallback (IAsyncResult result)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse (result);

        StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader (response.GetResponseStream ());
        string responseString = responseStream.ReadToEnd ();
        responseStream.Close ();

        ProcessResponse (responseString, request);
    }
```

ProcessResponse (responseString, request) looks like this:

```
    private static void ProcessResponse (string responseString, HttpWebRequest request)
    {
        string requestUrl = request.Address.ToString ();

        if (requestUrl.Contains (ShowSearchTag)) {
            List<TvShow> searchResults = TvDbParser.ParseTvShowSearchResults (responseString);
            TvShowSearchTimeoutClock.Enabled = false;
            OnTvShowSearchComplete (searchResults);
        } else if (requestUrl.Contains (MirrorListTag)) {
            MirrorList = TvDbParser.ParseMirrorList (responseString);
            SendRequestsOnHold ();
        } else if (requestUrl.Contains (TvShowBaseTag)) {
            TvShowBase showBase = TvDbParser.ParseTvShowBase (responseString);
            OnTvShowBaseRecieved (showBase);
        } else if (requestUrl.Contains (ImagePathReqTag)) {
            string showID = GetShowIDFromImagePathRequest (requestUrl);
            TvShowImagePath imagePath = TvDbParser.ParseTvShowImagePath (showID, responseString);
            OnTvShowImagePathRecieved (imagePath);
        }
    }
```

CreateAndDisplayTvShowWidget (TvShow show) is called when the event OnTvShowBaseRecieved (TvShow) is called, which is when I get tons error messages regarding NSAutoReleasePool...

The last two functions are part of what is supposed to be a cross-platform assembly, so I can't have any MonoMac-specific code in there...

I never call any auto-release or release code for my widgets, so I assume that the MonoMac bindings does this automatically as part of its garbage collection?

Comment: What else could I add to this question that might help people figure out what's wrong? I still can't get any closer to an answer...

Answer (score 0):

You can create autorelease pools at point within the call stack, you can even have multiple nested autorelease pools with the same call stack. So you should be able to create your autorelease pools in the async entry functions.

Answer (score 0):

You only need an NSAutoreleasePool if you use the auto-release features of objects. A solution is to create a NSAutoreleasePool around the code that manipulates auto-released objects (in the async callback).

**Edit:**

Have you tried to encapsulate the creation code with a `NSAutoreleasePool` ? As this is the only place where you call MonoMac code, this should solve the issue.

```
private void CreateAndDisplayTvShowWidget (TvShow show)
{
    using(NSAutoreleasePool pool = new NSAutoreleasePool())
    {
        var Widget = new TvShowWidgetController (show);
        Widget.OnRemoveWidget += ConfirmRemoveTvShow;

        Widget.View.SetFrameOrigin (new PointF (0, -150));
        Widget.View.SetFrameSize (new SizeF (ContentView.Frame.Width, 150));

        ContentView.AddSubview (Widget.View);
        show.ShowWidget = Widget;
    }
}
```

Note that even if you don't use auto-released objects directly, there are some case where the Cococa API use them udner the hood.

Comment: Still seem to get the errors. I don't get the errors before a new widget is added or a Widget is updated, so when the application starts up for the first time and just creates widgets from a save-file, it works fine with or with the "using" statement...

Comment: I realized that you are creating widgets in secondary threads. I don't think it is a good idea to create widgets outside the main UI thread because Cocoa like any other UI framework is not thread-safe. What you can do is to defer the invocation of the `CreateAndDisplayTvShowWidget` method on the main UI thread by using the `InvokeOnMainThread` method (http://mono.ximian.com/monomac-docs/MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject.InvokeOnMainThread%20(MonoMac.Foundation.NSAction)).

Comment: Ok, tried the following in the function that decides if new widgets should be created or not... InvokeOnMainThread (delegate { CreateAndDisplayTvShowWidget (show); }); ... No change...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it was the response.GetResponseStream that was the problem. I surrounded this code with...

```
using (NSAutoreleasePool pool = new NSAutoreleasePool()) {
}
```

... and that solved my problem.